# How to write data to an android file in C#?

Tags: c#, android, file, usb, mtp

When I attempt to open a file for writing using the MTP (Media Transfer Protocol).

It gives me the error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

```
IPortableDeviceResources resources;
file.content.Transfer(out resources);

file.parentDevice.Connect();

PortableDeviceApiLib.IStream wpdStream;
uint optimalTransferSize = 0;

resources.GetStream(file.Id, 
ref PortableDeviceConstants.WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT, 
PortableDeviceConstants.STGM_WRITE, 
ref optimalTransferSize, 
out wpdStream);
```

It throws the error on `GetStream` call.

When ever I use `STGM_READ` for read access.

It works just fine, but it does not work for `STGM_WRITE` or `STGM_READWRITE` access.

When I looked at someone else's method at copying a file on github. They never use `STGM_WRITE` and instead delete the original file and recreate the file using `CreateObjectWithPropertiesAndData` to get the stream.

So how can I write to an existing file using MTP?